# PowerBi Pivot creates repeating values and inserts extra nulls

Tags: powerbi, pivot, powerbi-desktop

This is probably going to come out with a really simple solution, but I am having trouble with a simple pivot in PowerBI.

I have a table where I have the costs of different utilities in one column, by month. I want to pivot the different utility types into separate columns, so I just have one row of data per month, with the different utility types across the top.

A simple pivot for some reason puts a bunch of nulls in and repeats the Months column, and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdSbp.png)

[Final Table with Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgjJM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eyes glossed over that first column, not realizing the unique IDs in that column were causing the problem. I got rid of EngieTable_ID and my table works now.